# What is the most simple JavaScript HTMLEncode lib/function implementation?

Tags: javascript, html, encode, html-entities

I'm looking for a js function or lib that'll convert special chars like `™` to `&trade;`, does anyone know of any? I'm looking for the simplest one that I can find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are [HTML named entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html) and they're not a best solution — better use a numerical entities. Why numerical entities are better? Cause you don't have any map like `©` → `&copy;`. All you need is a character itself.

```
function abc(input) {
    var output = "";
    var allowedChars = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
         var char     = input.charAt(i);
         var charCode = input.charCodeAt(i);

         if (isNaN(charCode)) {
             continue;
         }

         if (allowedChars.indexOf(char) > -1) {
             output += char;
         } else {
             output += "&#" + charCode + ";";
         }
    }

    return output;
}

alert(abc("Hello world! ©™汉")); // Hello&#32;world&#33;&#32;&#169;&#8482;&#27721
```

Comment: Your solution is robust, but `&copy;` is a lot more readable than `&169;` in case that matters to the asker.

Comment: nice Crozin thanks!, readability of the source didn't matter to me, but I guess it might to others.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a library or function for that, but if you deal exclusively with Unicode, you shouldn't have to encode any special characters beyond `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;`, and `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1):

Really all you need is a lookup table.  There's a nice big list of HTML entities here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Your lookup code would look like this:

```
var characters = [];
characters['"'] = '&quot;';
characters['\''] = '&apos;';
characters['&'] = '&amp;';
characters['<'] = '&lt;';
characters['>'] = '&gt;';
// ...
```

Then just look through each character in your text, and start replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did. I went [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) and did this code in firebug:

```
ret = ''; td = jQuery('table.reference td'); for (var i = 0; i < (td.length / 4); i++) ret += td.eq(i).text() + ' ' + td.eq(i + 2).text() + ' ' + td.eq(i + 3).text() + ' ' + td.eq(i + 3).text()+ '\n'; ret;
```

and got this:

```
"" &quot; quotation mark quotation mark &#34; quotation mark ' ' &quot; ' &#39; &#39; quotation mark &#39; &apos; (does not work in IE) &apos; (does not work in IE) ' &apos; (does not work in IE) apostrophe  apostrophe  &#39; apostrophe  & & &apos; (does not work in IE) & &#38; &#38; apostrophe  &#38; &amp; &amp; & &amp; ampersand ampersand &#38; ampersand < < &amp; < &#60; &#60; ampersand &#60; &lt; &lt; < &lt; less-than less-than &#60; less-than > > &lt; > &#62; &#62; less-than &#62; &gt; &gt; > &gt; greater-than greater-than &#62; greater-than     &gt;   &#160; &#160; greater-than &#160; &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp; non-breaking space non-breaking space &#160; non-breaking space ¡ ¡ &nbsp; ¡ &#161; &#161; non-breaking space &#161; &iexcl; &iexcl; ¡ &iexcl; inverted exclamation mark inverted exclamation mark &#161; inverted exclamation mark ¢ ¢ &iexcl; ¢ &#162; &#162; inverted exclamation mark &#162; &cent; &cent; ¢ &cent; cent cent &#162; cent £ £ &cent; £ &#163; &#163; cent &#163; &pound; &pound; £ &pound; pound pound &#163; pound ¤ ¤ &pound; ¤ &#164; &#164; pound &#164; &curren; &curren; ¤ &curren; currency currency &#164; currency ¥ ¥ &curren; ¥ &#165; &#165; currency &#165; &yen; &yen; ¥ &yen; yen yen &#165; yen ¦ ¦ &yen; ¦ &#166; &#166; yen &#166; &brvbar; &brvbar; ¦ &brvbar; broken vertical bar broken vertical bar &#166; broken vertical bar § § &brvbar; § &#167; &#167; broken vertical bar &#167; &sect; &sect; § &sect; section section &#167; section ¨ ¨ &sect; ¨ &#168; &#168; section &#168; &uml; &uml; ¨ &uml; spacing diaeresis spacing diaeresis &#168; spacing diaeresis © © &uml; © &#169; &#169; spacing diaeresis &#169; &copy; &copy; © &copy; copyright copyright &#169; copyright ª ª &copy; ª &#170; &#170; copyright &#170; &ordf; &ordf; ª &ordf; feminine ordinal indicator feminine ordinal indicator &#170; feminine ordinal indicator « « &ordf; « &#171; &#171; feminine ordinal indicator &#171; &laquo; &laquo; « &laquo; angle quotation mark (left) angle quotation mark (left) &#171; angle quotation mark (left) ¬ ¬ &laquo; ¬ &#172; &#172; angle quotation mark (left) &#172; &not; &not; ¬ &not; negation negation &#172; negation ­ ­ &not; ­ &#173; &#173; negation &#173; &shy; &shy; ­ &shy; soft hyphen soft hyphen &#173; soft hyphen ® ® &shy; ® &#174; &#174; soft hyphen &#174; &reg; &reg; ® &reg; registered trademark registered trademark &#174; registered trademark ¯ ¯ &reg; ¯ &#175; &#175; registered trademark &#175; &macr; &macr; ¯ &macr; spacing macron spacing macron &#175; spacing macron ° ° &macr; ° &#176; &#176; spacing macron &#176; &deg; &deg; ° &deg; degree degree &#176; degree ± ± &deg; ± &#177; &#177; degree &#177; &plusmn; &plusmn; ± &plusmn; plus-or-minus  plus-or-minus  &#177; plus-or-minus  ² ² &plusmn; ² &#178; &#178; plus-or-minus  &#178; &sup2; &sup2; ² &sup2; superscript 2 superscript 2 &#178; superscript 2 ³ ³ &sup2; ³ &#179; &#179; superscript 2 &#179; &sup3; &sup3; ³ &sup3; superscript 3 superscript 3 &#179; superscript 3 ´ ´ &sup3; ´ &#180; &#180; superscript 3 &#180; &acute; &acute; ´ &acute; spacing acute spacing acute
```

Shouldn't be too hard to mold this to your specific needs